# COIN-OR CBC Lotsize variable creation and MPS file of formulation

Tags: gurobi, cvxpy, coin-or-cbc, mps-format

I am working on a Linear Programming Formulation where I require some variables to take values from a predefined set. I was pointed out to use the CBC Lotsize Variable Type (https://github.com/coin-or/Cbc/discussions/516#discussioncomment-3007885). However the CBC C++ libraries use MPS format to be fed into them. I am not finding any way to create MPS file of my formulation. Please suggest the way forward...

FYI: Another similar request to Gurobi is pending: https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/9160893511185-Requesting-a-new-type-of-variable-introduction

Comment: This is something you can model directly with binary variables https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/mio.html#fixed-set-of-values

Comment: Absolutely correct! This is what I am targeting. I wish to compare and show that Binary Modelling would take more solution time compared to the other method of modelling in which case I would require Lotsize/Bucket Variables...

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use Gurobi for modelling the entire formulation. Then save the model in any formal you wish.

Gurobi supports saving the mathematical model in .lp , .mps as well as many other formats...